# bash read stdin after piped input

Tags: bash

I am having trouble getting bash to relinquish control of the pipe to stdin. I want to pass in the username and password to a program and then have that same program read from stdin rather than the pipe! This is what I have tried:

```
alias pandora='echo -e "$(cat ~/.musik/name)\n$(cat ~/.musik/pass | base64 --decode)" | pianobar'
```

That's in my `.bashrc`. First, it cat's the username/password files and then pipes that into `pianobar` (pandora in the terminal). The username and password get in there, however, pianobar is expecting more input. Pianobar is asking for a number (to be able to play, for example, station *12*), but when I type and hit enter, nothing happens because for some reason, it isn't expecting it to come from there.

How do I get the pipe to "relinquish" control?

Note: I have also tried

```
echo "$(cat ~/.musik/name)
$(cat ~/.musik/pass | base64 --decode) 
" >>> pianobar
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options you can try:

Easy way: (may not work for all sorts of commands (like pianobar in this case)

```
alias pandora='{ echo -e "$(cat ~/.musik/name)\n$(cat ~/.musik/pass | base64 --decode)"; cat; } | pianobar'
```

Or with a bit cleanup & removal of [`UUOC`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html):

```
alias pandora='{ cat ~/.musik/name; base64 --decode < ~/.musik/pass; cat; } | pianobar'
```

Better way: use [`expect`](http://man.cx/expect) script. I could have written the script, but I don't know the login prompt that your application gives.

Comment: I'd go with `{ cat; echo; cat | base64; cat; } | pianobar` instead of this to avoid the unnecessary `echo -e`, etc.

Comment: ^^ Agreed. I also have same opinion. I just preferred making minimal changes to OP's script. But edited giving that solution too.

Comment: Using an `expect` script is actually more certain to work the same way real TTY input does -- if the program varies its behavior on the return value of isatty(stdin), the `cat` hack may not work.

Comment: ^^ Right. But `isatty(stdin)` is usually used for login stage. If Op's existing code is allowing login using redirected stdin, then quite **likely** (not certain), next cat would work too...

Comment: Ah, so I literally need it to relinquish control because it may need to read more than just one input. There are two problems: (1) you have to press enter (and pianobar reads key input like raw mode or something);  (2) there is more than one input... so I could do `while : ; do cat; done` I guess.. any thoughts?

Comment: It appears as though expect will work, so thank you. I don't have time to mess around with it today, though.

Comment: `cat` doesn't stop on "enter". It'll keep reading forever. But `expect` is a much better idea. As is getting `pianobar` to gain support for actual credential storage.

Comment: `cat` would not stop after enter. If your program does not use `isatty` or `termio*` operations, using the `cat` option, you could probably use your application in an interactive way. But `expect` does it in a much better way. (That even passes isatty test.)

Comment: @EtanReisner you are correct, but you still have the problem with blocking calls. Pianobar can read keys. So, for example, if I wanted to pause pianobar, I would have to do `p[Enter]` instead of just `p` (which is how it is when I rub pianobar normally).

Comment: You could try using `IFS= read -N 1` instead of `cat` with a new enough bash (or `IFS= read -n 1 -d ''` with older bash) and seeing if that lets pianobar work "normally". `cat` is line-buffering. The pipe may buffer also.

Comment: Are there other options, like dd/unbuffer, which will pass the stdin to stdout, one character per line?

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to configure pianobar auto login:

```
    mkdir ~/.config/pianobar/ && cd ~/.config/pianobar/ && touch config
```

Run ^^^ in your command line then put the following in your new config file

```
    # User
    user = (Your Pandora email)
    password = (Your Pandora password)
```

https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar/blob/e945578ab22912049f1e547ce7b25b01089f7590/contrib/config-example